# No option for Unit Test in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm learning android development online and when I open  android studio, it doesn't have any option for unit test on the bottom-left corner. [Here's the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SH8C8.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Active build variant does not have a test artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59153826/active-build-variant-does-not-have-a-test-artifact)

Answer (score 0):

What you are showing on your screenshot are the `BuildVariants` which would normally be **debug** or **release** if you have not touch the `build.gradle` file.

To run your test, there are may ways:

1- In the `Terminal` tab in the bottom panel you can run

> ./gradlew test

2- In the `Project Structure View` you can step over you test file or test folder, right click and select **Run Test**, or hit CTRL+SHFT+R

3- In the `Gradle` tab at the right panel, the **test task** is located inside **verification**

Comment: Actually what I meant was that "Test Artifact" selector is missing from where we could select "Unit Test".